# MYSQL Query same field twice

Tags: php, mysql, field

I have the following query which doesn't return results:

```
1. SELECT *
2. FROM wp_postmeta pm
3. LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
4. LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
5. LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
6. WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
7. AND p.post_type = 'post' 
8. AND p.post_date < NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
9. AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
10. AND tt.term_id IN(3)
11. AND (pm.meta_key = 'EndDate' AND pm.meta_value > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)) 
12. AND (pm.meta_key = 'NumPrizes' AND pm.meta_value > 1)
13. GROUP BY ID
14. ORDER BY p.ID DESC
```

The problem occurs because of lines 11 and 12. I can remove one or the other and get results, but I need both in order to get what I want.

What I want is to get results where pm.meta_key EndDate is greater than today AND where pm.meta_key NumPrizes is greater than 0.

The idea is to output the total number of prizes in the database.

The database is built by wordpress, so I can't change it. The way it works is meta_key has a value which is the name of the field and meta_value is the actual value of the meta_key.

Example of wp_postmeta table:

```
meta_id     post_id    meta_key   meta_value
1           45         EndDate    2012-01-01    <- too old
2           45         NumPrizes  5             <- since too old, don't count
3           76         EndDate    2012-07-03    <- valid date but...
4           76         NumPrizes  1             <- only 1 prize so don't count
5           90         EndDate    2012-06-02    <- valid date and
6           90         NumPrizes  4             <- more than one prize so count it
7           192        EndDate    2012-09-01    <- valid date and
8           192        NumPrizes  9             <- more than one prize so count it
```

Expected output: Number of prizes is 13. (4+9 = 13).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Of course is not possible that a single column take two differents values at a time:

> ```
> 11. AND pm.meta_key = 'EndDate'      <<-- big error: column can't take two
> 12. AND pm.meta_key = 'NumPrizes'    <<--      differents values at a time
> ```

You should normalize table and/or write a right query:

```
1. SELECT *
2. FROM wp_postmeta pm
3. LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
4. LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
5. LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
6. WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
7. AND p.post_type = 'post' 
8. AND p.post_date < NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
9. AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
10. AND tt.term_id IN(3)
11. AND (pm.meta_key = 'EndDate' AND pm.meta_value > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)) 
12. AND exists (
          select 1 from wp_postmeta pm2 where
          pm2.post_id  = pm.post_id and
          pm2.meta_key = 'NumPrizes' AND pm2.meta_value > 1
    )
13. GROUP BY ID
14. ORDER BY p.ID DESC
```

**EDITED**

Jonathan, I don't know your espected result because in question you talk about a single scalar result (number 13) but in your query you join main table with other tables. I hope this code I write here can help to you, but you should to adapt it to your particular case.

```
1. SELECT *, sum( __your_prizes_agrregation__ )
2. FROM wp_postmeta pm
3. LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
4. LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
5. LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
6. WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
7. AND p.post_type = 'post' 
8. AND p.post_date < NOW()+INTERVAL 1 DAY 
9. AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
10. AND tt.term_id IN(3)
11. AND exists (
          select 1 from wp_postmeta pm2 where
          pm2.post_id  = pm.post_id and
          pm2.meta_key = 'EndDate' AND 
          pm2.meta_value > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    )
12. AND exists (
          select 1 from wp_postmeta pm2 where
          pm2.post_id  = pm.post_id and
          pm2.meta_key = 'NumPrizes' AND pm2.meta_value > 1
    )
13. GROUP BY ID
14. ORDER BY p.ID DESC
```

Comment: but how do I access the value for NumPrizes? I want to output the total number of prizes but I can't do that using your code...

Comment: +1 simply for taking the time to write this extremely long and verbose query for him! Bravo! :)